# Symfony 1.4 Validation

Tags: forms, symfony1, validation

Can anyone tell me how could i validate the data on the other page (where was not created the form object)?

The thing is: on the page 'A' i am creating the form object with its own validators and showing the form to the user. But the action goes to the page 'B', where i need to validate the data.

I want to do something like this (page 'B'):

```
$form = new someForm();
$form->bind($this->getRequest()->getParameter('data'));
if($form->isValid())
{
  print 'true';
}
else
{
  print 'false';
}
```

But as you can imagine, it will print 'false'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it happens due to CSRF protection of forms in Symfony

Try to use this code

```
$form = new someForm();
$form->disableLocalCSRFProtection();
$form->bind($this->getRequest()->getParameter('data'));
if($form->isValid())
{
  print 'true';
}
else
{
  print 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could solve this like:

```
public function executeFoo($request){
  $this->form = new fooForm();
  $this->getUser()->setAttribute('tmpForm', $this->form);
}
```

in your form the action has to point to module/bar
there you can do:

```
public function executeBar($request){
  $this->forward404Unless($form = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('tmpForm'));
  $form->bind($this->getRequest()->getParameter('data'))
  // and so on
}
```